# acquiring string output when i hit enter when input is finished

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream> // to generate the hexadecimal representation of a number
#include<string>

using std::string;

int main()
{
    const string hexdigits("0123456789ABCDEF");    //possible hexdigits

    std::cout << "enter the series of numbers between 0 and 15"
        << "separated by space. Hit enter when finished: " 
        << std::endl; //line to be printed on screen

    string result; // it will hold hexadecimal representation of the number

    string::size_type n; // undefined string variable will hold numbers

    while (std::cin >> n)  // input number with just spaces

    {
        if (n < hexdigits.size()) // compares n with  hexdigits size
        {
            result += hexdigits[n]; // storing string output in result 
        }
    }

    std::cout << "your hex number is: " << result << std::endl; //output result   

    return 0;
}
```

when I press ENTER after input, the output hex is not automatically generated. I have to use escape sequence \n after input, to  proceed to output. how can I get my output with just hitting ENTER after give input numbers?

I tried using getline to get the whole line and exit, as given below

```
while(std::getline(std::cin, n))
```

but it gave error E0304

> no instance for overloaded function 'std::getline' matches the argument list".

Comment: OT: Do you really need all these empty lines in your code?

Comment: stack overflow asked me to put 4 spaces between each line of code, for it to be proper. apologies

Comment: Now you screwed your code even more. I'd recommend you should read the [code formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: It's 4 spaces in the beginning of each line, to get it formatted as code

Comment: `while(std::getline(std::cin, n))` any line is a string, `n` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `std::string` argument to `getline`. The conversion is not correct either in several ways, but there are a lot of examples that show how to convert a hex string to a number. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdlib.h"

int main()
{
    std::string line;

    if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        unsigned int value = strtoul(line.c_str(), NULL, 16);
        std::cout << "your hex number is: " << value << std::endl; //output result   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And as usual, note that the value of the output number is limited to 32-bits in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit confused about *types* and *logic*. Firstly `while(std::getline(std::cin, n))` does not work because `n` is not a string, getline only works with strings. Secondly even if getline worked with numbers the logic would not be correct because you want to input a *single* line but a while loop with getline would input *multiple* lines.

The answer is to use getline once to input a single line and then use a while loop to convert each of the numbers in the single line. To do this you have to know how to read numbers from a string (instead of from the console). I guess this is the part you are missing.

Here's some sample code (untested)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string hexdigits("0123456789ABCDEF");    //possible hexdigits
    std::cout << "enter the series of numbers between 0 and 15"
        << "separated by space. Hit enter when finished: " 
        << std::endl;

    std::string line;
    if (getline(std::cin, line)) // read a line
    {
        std::istringstream buf(line);
        unsigned result = 0, n;
        while (buf >> n)  // read numbers from the line
        {
            if (n < hexdigits.size())
            {
                result += hexdigits[n]; 
            }
        }
        std::cout << "your hex number is: " << result << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BTW try to avoid commenting the obvious, comments like `// compares n with  hexdigits size` add nothing to your code.